# Is it ever okay to ask obvious questions?

Tags: discussion

So, considering that when you hover over the up-vote option of a question, the clarification text says "shows research effort" you would think that questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array?rq=1) would get down-voted because anyone who actually read the documentation knows how easy this is in python.

I'm not trying to discriminate at all, this just happened to be the question that prompted me to ask. In fact, I have seen some very, very trivial questions with 1k + up-votes in the past. This is presumably the result of all of the other beginners who didn't want to read the documentation.

So my question is as follows: If the point is to create resources for the future, If we can think of a question that would directly help many people who are just searching for quick answers, but could also easily be solved with a little bit of patience, Should the question be posted?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68884/discussion-on-question-by-lukep-is-it-ever-okay-to-ask-obvious-questions).

Comment: Is it ever okay to ask obvious questions?  
No.  You see the recursive irony in the answer, don't you?  Well, then, no.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

My personal thought (and what I've used to guide my moderation practices), is yes. We want to be the canonical resource for programming problems.

But the stars have to align *just so* to make that happen:

- The question has to be one that has stumped a lot of new developers (in this case, you notice that question has over 600K views, that's a lot)
- It has to have relatively simple text; not overly complicated. Well explained. Concise.
- The answer has to either:

  1. Be equally concise and helpful, or
  2. Explain the topic in such a way that the question becomes more useful.

If those criteria aren't met, it's very likely that the community will vote to close the post.  There is no 'one size fits all' answer; it all comes down to the particulars of the question and whether or not the answers make it 'worth it'.

Comment: I should think that some _simple_ questions might be a good fit for SO as long as they are not dups. Documentation does not have _all_ the answers. Questions ranked a touch higher than obvious might have a good fit. Ultimately the community will decide though.

Comment: @Matt: Ideally, these questions will become canonical _dup targets_.  The example question has [26 linked questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/3277503), including 4 closed as duplicates. This is a sort of a win - win situation: people new to Python can get a quick answer and experienced Pythonistas don't have to see the same question asked over and over.

Comment: I think that first bullet point is one of the most important ones for determining whether a question of the nature will survive. The last is a very close second.

Comment: There's one more thing that a question can do to qualify for hits - match a string *exactly*. Exceptions, compiler/debugger output,  event log entries, and syslog messages are worth their weight in gold when included in a question. When an error string matches, I know I'm looking at a potential solution if someone has answered the question.

Comment: The first bullet point is indeed an important one, but IMHO is largely made irrelevant by age, "except in that magic sweet stop case" where this is indeed a canonical answer and not subject to change. Language based questions mostly fit that criteria. But framework and server systems largely mean the older answer is either incorrect or not optimal. Other answers can be added, but tend to fall into obscurity. There are solid cases where new answers are not duplicates and are truly informative answers to build on. The older answers should then be "obsoleted"

Answer (score 137):

What is obvious to you is not necessarily obvious to everyone else and so many manuals are written for people who don't really need the manual. Manuals tend to be loaded of technical terms and you have to parse a lot of things to find what you are actually trying to do.

The question you pointed to is a good example. I started reading a book about Python but never really played around with it, so I figured I was in perfect position to test run it. Let's see what it takes to answer the question using Python's manual:

I found the page about input-output. It's 2,500 words long. Starts with output formatting. Oh wait there is a "reading writing files", let's check that. Open returns a file object bla bla bla. How do I get an array? Ah, file object methods. There is a .read method, a .readline method, a readlines method and no mention of array in the whole page (I guess in Python, you'd use a list).

And the Python manual looks like it's actually pretty good, but compare that experience with finding the SO question on Google:

You search your question in natural language, land on SO, check the first answer and it says:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

> I'm guessing that you meant list and not array.

You get exactly what you need, you can continue on what you were doing in 30 seconds, and you even know not to waste your time looking for documentation on arrays because apparently the thing you want is called a list.

All these upvotes to the question and the answer? That's people who saved a bundle of time because SO allowed the question. It was worth it.

Comment: Sorry, are we talking about the Python language? The one that there are tons of easy, clear tutorials, blog posts, and cheat sheets on?

Comment: @DavidConrad I'd prefer getting the information I need from a single SO post rather than sifting through an entire tutorial, no matter how clear and well-written

Comment: @DavidConrad (and any other fans of manuals): Hey, I am a huge fan of manuals. I think the tutorial in the standard Python documentation is one of the best, and it's how I learned Python myself. I do think more people should be reading manuals. I do think that folks who *never* investigate things deeply for themselves, and who *only* ever ask questions on Google and Q&A sites, will usually wind up with a poor or incomplete understanding of things. But y'know what? **That's OK.** It's not SO's mission to make its readers better programmers. It's SO's mission to answer *specific* questions.

Comment: @JohnY: you can be excellent programmer and still find the question useful. Not every programmer have to know Python well e.g., I sometimes have to edit programs in unfamiliar programming languages -- it would be waste of time to read a manual instead of a simple google query in this case. Also, a beginner programmer might write a program before memorizing the manual i.e., a manual should not be *the only* way to learn

Comment: @JohnY I am a strong believer in personal development and ongoing study, but there is a time for everything. If I am trying to crank out a small utility, or if I have a tight deadline and I need a tidbit of Python code to load a file in an array, I don't want to start studying Python I/O operations and Python data structures. Loading a file in an array is a solved problem, I just need the codez so I can get back to doing what I need to so. I'll make a note to look into Python I/O next time I have some down time.

Comment: @DavidConrad Python was just the example discussed here. The little I have seen of Python's doc/tutorials, it looks pretty good, but like Marks, if you need a specific tidbit of "how-to" information, nothing beats a straight answer.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I never said a manual should be the only way to learn.

Comment: @JohnY: you implied that such questions might be useful only to bad programmers

Comment: @Sylverdrag: I'm not sure if you're trying to give a rebuttal to my comment. If so, you missed my point entirely. My comment was in full support of your answer (and Question Mark's comment).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Nothing of the sort. Please read carefully. I said that people who **only** ask quick questions (i.e. **never** do any "study")... will **usually** have poor or incomplete understanding. I never even said that it was impossible to learn solely by asking quick questions.

Comment: @JohnY then how do you suggest to interpret *"It's not SO's mission to make its readers better programmers."*?

Comment: I don't have any problem with the SO question-and-answer format. Hey, I'm an SO user, too. What I have a problem with is the attitude that manuals, tutorials, etc. are *sooo* hard that people would just be at sea if they had to rely on them.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I suggest taking it literally and at face value. It is simply not SO's mission to make its readers better programmers. I believe SO would *like* its readers to become better programmers, and I believe SO often *does* make its readers better programmers.  But that's not its **mission**.  Its mission is to create a comprehensive repository of specific, directed questions and answers.  Also be clear, anyone can use this site.  Some of the programmers here, both askers and answerers, are world class, I have no doubt about that at all.

Comment: @DavidConrad can you think of a language that *doesn't* have tons of easy, clear tutorials, blog posts, and cheat sheets?

Comment: Even for what seems simple, lots of tutorials online use questionable/insecure/terrible techniques, and either have no feedback or no ability to provide feedback.  SO's mechanisms are great at separating the good from the bad.

Comment: @onewhaleid COBOL ;-)

Comment: @onewhaleid: C++ comes to mind immediately.  The differences between the '03 and '11 standards are extremely broad and can be very subtle (think "sequence points" vs. "sequence before/after/indeterminate")  The extreme subtleties in some languages mean that clear manuals, cheat sheets, etc., are not enough.  This is why Bjarne rates himself as an "8" in C++. Truly understanding sometimes requires back-and-forth with other true experts in a language (sometimes from the applicable Standard committee).

Answer (score 12):

> If we can think of a question that would directly help many people

If you can think of such a question that has not already been ask and answered, please go ahead. (That is increasingly unlikely, though)

Answer (score 11):

While I somehow agree with the other answers, I give the following *potential* disadvantage to consider.

The more "basic" the level of questions is, the more possible questions you have. The question in the OP can have multiple basic variations: "How to read a file into a dictionary?", "How to read a file into a set?", "How to read every n-th line of a file?" ("... into an array", "... into a dictionary", "into a set"). There is a **huge** number of possible variations.

This implies that we accept the fact that people don't want to read anything that doesn't answer their **whole question directly** with a solution on a plate, even though the answer could be easily composed from two other SO questions, for example.

---

**TL;DR**

This in turn may lead to a low [SNR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) in the future. In our current example, people looking for something more elaborate that concerns files and lists in Python will be flooded by tons of all possible basic combinations of these notions in such basic questions.

---

I'm not saying that this is a definitive argument against such questions, but I think it's worth considering in the context of where do we want to put the boundary.

Comment: Further to this point, there is the issue of multiple languages targeting a single platform and getting platform questions for individual languages. The "duplicates" should not be marked as such, but often are.

Answer (score 4):

If you know of a question that would "*would directly help many people*" and indeed has not been asked and answered before, than go ahead post **and answer** it yourself.

If, for whatever reason, you do not want to gain reputation from such post, you can turn it into [`community wiki`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki).